# How to use Rails.root in config files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

We have a config YAML file for our Rails 3 application with a file location something like this for each Rails env:

```
Production:
  file_path: "#{Rails.root}/tmp/foobar"

Test:
  file_path: "#{Rails.root}/tmp/test"
```

This 'file_path' directory changes depending on the target machine where our app is deployed.  So we were hoping we could use this template string with the replacement Rails.root var. However during execution, it doesn't appear to substitute in the actual Rails.root value for #{Rails.root} when we load and use this string from our config file. So we have to use gsub. This feels rather awkward and I'm hoping there is a different way to specify this in our config YAML file so it does the substitution automatically at run time.
And yes there are several alternative ways we could solve this, but in general my question is how to use Rails vars like this from a YAML config file.

Comment: FWIW this is a potential security vulnerability, in that the config can be changed to point to any directory on the system. I would remove the base path, and explicitly set it wherever you're loading this config.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use embed ERB commands in a YAML file which is how YAML-based test fixtures work and allow you to do stuff like:

```
record:
  updated_at: <%= Time.now %>
```

The solution is to run the file through ERB and then YAML:

```
config = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/config.yml")).result)[Rails.env]
config['file_path'] # now contains your full path
```

Your YAML file will need to be slightly updated to use the ERB output expression - so make the following updates:

```
production:
  file_path: <%= "#{Rails.root}/tmp/foobar" %>

test:
  file_path: <%= "#{Rails.root}/tmp/test" %>
```

Comment: Thanks! I like your suggested solution, cleaner than mine, and looks like the typical way to do this sort of thing...